# OnPostExecute Method is Executing before Doinbackground Fetching Data from Server To Local

Tags: android, android-asynctask

1. In my Android async task class, I'm fetching data from an Azure server to local database inside `DoinBackground` method
2. But before finishing the `DoinBackground` method, it's executing the `OnPostExecute` method
3. Inside `OnPostExecute` method I am disabling the `ProgressBar`

Help me to solve this issue.

My code:

```
public class AsyncTaskSync_UserGroupMappingTableClass extends AsyncTask<String, String, Boolean>
{
      {

       @Override
       protected void onPreExecute()
       {
           super.onPreExecute();
       }

       @Override
       protected Boolean doInBackground(String... values)
       {
           try
           {
                mToDoTable_Form5_SPINNER_DataTable456_ServerAzure
                                .execute(new TableQueryCallback<FormsObjectTable2TaskHopsSPinnerValues>() {
                                    public void onCompleted(List<FormsObjectTable2TaskHopsSPinnerValues> result, int count, Exception exception, ServiceFilterResponse response) {
                       if (exception == null) {
                          if (!result.equals("")) {
                              for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
                                  /*Table 5 SPinner Data Table*/
                                  IdValue_TableValue5 = result.get(i).getId();
                                  ImeiStringval1_TableValue5 = result.get(i).getImeINumberValOne();
                                  Spinner_IDStringVal1_TableValue5 = result.get(i).getSpinner_id_StringOne();
                                  Spinner_data_StringVal1_TableValue5 = result.get(i).getSPinner_data_Value_StringOne();
                                  Log.i("From SErver DataBase", " Spinner : " + ImeiStringval1_TableValue5 + " : " + Spinner_IDStringVal1_TableValue5 + " : " + Spinner_data_StringVal1_TableValue5);
                                  Asynxfor_DATAinsert5_SpinnerTable(IdValue_TableValue5, ImeiStringval1_TableValue5, Spinner_IDStringVal1_TableValue5, Spinner_data_StringVal1_TableValue5);
                              }
                          } else {
                              Log.i("Data Retrieval Not Found", "No Data In Server For Specific IMEI......!");
                          }
                     } else {
                          Log.i("SOme Exception", "Data Retrieval From Server FORMTABLE1 Data......!");
                          exception.printStackTrace();
                     }
                 }
           });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();;
            Log.i("Data Retrieval", "Exception Occur......!");
        }

        // PrgDialog.dismiss();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean results)
    {
        try
        {
            Log.i("DONE ", "Data Sync Done Successfully 5 Spinner Values");
            PrgDialog.dismiss();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("Exception ", "Post Excecute");
        }
    }
};
```

**Edit 1**

My Logcat message:

```
// From OnPostExecute first Executing also disabling the Progressbar
DONE: Data Sync Done Successfully Form Master 1 

// From Doinbackground
From Server database
```

Comment: Could you share the logcat?

Comment: DONE: Data Sync Done Successfully Form Master 1

Comment: I would imagine that the `execute()` method is itself asynchronous, which is why it takes a callback object argument. That is, you don't need to put it in an `AsyncTask`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requests you are doing inside `doInBackground` are made asynchronusly that's means that `doInBackground` is already execute before you get the `TableQueryCallback`. In other words It's a thread which is launching another thread. I think you do not need to surround it in an `AsyncTask`, you could handle your respond on `TableQueryCallback.onCompleted()` with a Handler or an Interface.

Comment: Thank you friend, Its Worked- inside that OnCompleted Method I called ProgressBar Disabling .